# Tensorflow dataset.shuffle seems not shuffle without repeat()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

My code has similar pattern with [tensorflow 2.0 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/advanced).
I want my dataset object to reshuffle in every epochs.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['a','b','c','d'])
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)

for epoch in range(10):
    for d in dataset:
        print(d)
```

Result:

```
tf.Tensor(b'c', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'a', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'b', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'd', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'c', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'a', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'b', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'd', shape=(), dtype=string)
...
```

It seems the dataset doesn't shuffle for each epoch.
Should I call .shuffle() for each epoch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should call `.shuffle` during the inner loop. Moreover, it is better to do not mix python code and TensorFlow code when pure tf.* method equivalent to the Python statements are available.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
# dataset = dataset.shuffle(2)


@tf.function
def loop():
    for epoch in tf.range(10):
        for d in dataset.shuffle(2):
            tf.print(d)


loop()
```

The loop call produces the different values every time (and `tf.print` prints the content of the `tf.Tensor`, differently from `print` that prints the object).